# Double UV unwraps

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I apparently accidentally made 2 UV layers and so the bottom UV layer is ghosting onto the second layer (see photo)[image]. Is there any way to delete the selected UV?

Comment: You can't make two UV faces for a mesh face on one UV map. Probably your mesh is duplicated. Delete one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Your UVs are alright. It's just a basic logic of 3d Softwares to repeat the texture outside the texture.  So you just need to scale down the Uvs if you don't want them to repeat
.

Comment: Or change the Image Texture Node from Repeat to Clip